# A simple inequality involving product xyz and xy

Tags: inequality

I am trying to verify that $xyz -xy-xz-zy \geq -\frac {8}{27}$ when $x+y+z=1$ and $x,y,z$ positive, preferably without resolving to calculus.

It seems like a standard result but I couldn't come up with some basic application of AM-GM or Muirhead's inequality

Any input is welcome

Comment: Maybe dividing both sides of what you need to prove, by $xyz$ helps? (proving that inequality is equivalent to proving this one)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Not entirely clear to me how this can help me

Comment: Sorry, I realized it was roundabout and led to one of the answers below anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First observe that:
$$
(1 - x)(1 - y)(1 - z) = 1 - (x + y + z) + (xy + yz + xz) - xyz = (xy + yz + xz) - xyz
$$
Thus, your inequality is equivalent to the following:
$$
(1 - x)(1 - y)(1 - z) \leq \frac{8}{27}
$$
Indeed this holds, as by AM-GM:
$$
(1 - x)(1 - y)(1 - z) \leq \left(\frac{3 - (x + y + z)}{3}\right)^3 = \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^3 = \frac{8}{27}
$$

Comment: That's a neat proof thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The inequality is equivalent to $$(xy+yz+zx)(x+y+z) \leq xyz + {8\over27}(x+y+z)^3$$

which simplifies to

$$2xyz+\sum{x^2y}\leq{8\over27}(x+y+z)^3={8\over27}\sum{x^3}+{8\over9}\sum{xy^2}+{16\over9}xyz$$

which simplifies to

$$6xyz+3\sum{xy^2}\leq8\sum{x^3}$$

Note that
$$6xyz\leq 2\sum{x^3}$$
$$3\sum{xy^2}\;\leq6\sum{x^3}$$

The inequality is therefore proven.

Comment: Thank you! its great to have two views. I accepted the other one as it was slightly easier to follow and you both posted at the same time.

Comment: Yes I agree the other answer is smarter as well. My answer  is based on the "make everything of the same degree and see what happen" approach while the other answer needed some more insight.